# Android 'App not Installed' Error - Failed to delete .tmp file

Tags: android, apk

I'm trying to update my app by downloading the apk and open. But the response message is "App not installed".

**The logcat error:**

```
2020-12-10 13:49:26.822 1628-1654/? W/PackageManager: Package br.com.app signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!
2020-12-10 13:49:26.827 1503-1523/? E/installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl128035576.tmp: No such file or directory
2020-12-10 13:49:26.837 1628-5285/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {dat=file:///data/user_de/0/com.google.android.packageinstaller/no_backup/package2911160709080656908.apk flg=0x2000000 cmp=com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFailed (has extras)} from uid 10019
2020-12-10 13:49:26.928 10096-10096/? D/InstallFailed: Installation status code: 1
```

**Permissions on Manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

This error only happens if I generate the signed apk (using v1 and v2 signatures).

PS: Already tried to put "android:testOnly=false" (on Manifest and gradle.properties)

Comment: What was your solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had this problem months ago and it was a disaster for me, finally I realized that I had signed and deployed my app with DIFFERENT SIGN KEYS so I could not update my app cause it got stopped after updating and I should remove my app and then reinstall it.
You can also use ADB to see the actual log while you are updating your app its located on your pc where your android studio installation files are you can run it and see the logs.
ADB is a bridge that connects your pc to your android phone and it gives you more information than your android studio logcat about what's actually happening.
another problem that I guess you might have is that you dont update your database version number properly and there might be a conflict between your DB VERSION NUMBERS, But its just a guess.

Comment: The "different sign keys" is not my case. But can you explain how I use ADB to see the actual log?

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/quickly-install-adb/

Comment: Make sure your phone is connected to your pc and developer option is enabled on your phone then go to your sdk folder->platform-tools then open your preferred command line and look for ADB devices just write ADB devices in your command line

Comment: @VictorSoares have you found a solution? I'm having the same problem here but even with ADB I'm not able to fix it because the logcat is pretty extensive. Thanks in advance!